# Having reboot problems upgrading windows 7 to win 10 on toshiba c655

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, reboot

I tried upgrading Toshiba Satellite c655 from Win 7 to Win 10. Besides the process taking forever it will load all info and ask to reboot. Somewhere in the reboot process something fail and a message titled recover pops up

" It looks like Windows didn't load correctly. If you'd like to restart and try again, choose restart pc below. Otherwise choose see advanced options for troubleshooting tools and advanced options."

Problem is I can not revert back to win 7 at this point and I can not proceed with the install of Win 10. An option does come up for selective boot options in the troubleshoot/advanced options menu but I can't system restore, no backup; can't system image recovery; nothing there, startup repair doesn't fix the problem, not sure what to do with the command prompt, and then I can try startup setting which lets me try turing things off such as : 
enable low res vid mode, doesn't help
enable debug mode
enable boot logging
enable safe mode
disable driver signature enforcement 
disable early-lauch anti-malware protection
disable auto restart on system failure

I'm lost and I can't seem to unbrick this poor thing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dude try choosing "advanced options" and inside that "trouble shoot" then "start options" and then start windows in "safe mode". After starting in safe mode uninstall the graphics drivers. Windows should boot with basic drivers post that you can update the drivers from device manager or install the latest drivers from manufacturers WebSite.